# Store return values

Tags: teamcity

I have a teamcity plan which includes two steps, and I need to store the first step script return value in order to pass it to the second step. The problem is that the [python] script is run as follows:
`pipenv run python my_script.py --env_url %env_url%`

And even when I know that I can store return values using ##teamcity messages, I don't know how to save the return value of my_script.py due to  `pipenv run`

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Ihmo simplest way - redirect output into some file, specify this file as artifact, and make artifact dependency for second step. So, this file will appear for second step whenever you start it.

Answer (score 0):

In the same situation, I've just saved the information into a JSON file and read this file in the next step.